# using %s to change the name of a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a way to change the name of a list using `%s`? Here's an example:

```
dict1[key]=value

for x in dict1.keys():
    %s %(x)profile=[]
    if dict1[x]=1:
        %s %(x)profile.append('yes')
```

This code didn't work, but I'm looking for something that will give me 'n' lists, one for each `x` in `dict1.keys()`.

Comment: Wait, wat? How did you get that idea? It's **string** formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: no, you can't do exactly that but if you're a little more clear with your intentions (it's hard to tell with your pseudocode what you're looking to do), there is certainly a way you can do what you **need** to do even though you can't do what you're **trying** to do

Short and dangerous answer:  Actually yes you sort of can, but no you generally shouldn't

**edit** for your updated comment

So instead of having specifically named lists, what you want to use is another dictionary:

```
new_dict = {}
for key in dict1.keys()
    new_key = "%sprofile" % key
    if dict1[key] == 1:   # note your = is actually a SyntaxError
        new_dict[new_key] = ['yes']
    else:
        new_dict[new_key] = []
```

This would result in a new dictionary with keys named "(key)profile" and each value associated would be a list either with `"yes"` in it if the original dict's value was `1` for the original key, or an empty list.

Comment: i'm looking to go through each `key` in `dict1` and create a new list for each key that is named `%(key) profile` essentially, and then just append things to that list from the dict1 data.

Comment: just to clarify, the new lists are separate things from `dict1`, I realize my word choice wasn't very clear

Comment: Rather than trying to dynamically name local variables, you should store those lists by name in a new dict.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'a':0, 'b':0, 'c':1}

profile = { k:(['yes'] if v==1 else []) for k,v in dict1.iteritems() }

print profile
>>> {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': ['yes']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you ? :

```
dic = { 1:['a','h','uu'] , 3:['zer','rty'] , 4:['hj','125','qsd'] }

print 'BEFORE LOOP :\n\nglobals()==',globals()
print
print "keys of globals() not written __xxx__ :",' , '.join(u for u in globals() if not u.startswith('__'))
print '\n-----------------------------------------------------------------\nDURING LOOP :\n'
for x in dic:
    print 'x==',x
    globals()['L'+str(x)+'profile'] = dic[x]
    print 'keys of globals() not written __xxx__ :',' , '.join(u for u in globals() if not u.startswith('__'))

print '\n-----------------------------------------------------------------\nAFTER LOOP :\n'
print 'keys of globals() not written __xxx__ :',' , '.join(u for u in globals() if not u.startswith('__'))
print
for li in (L1profile,L3profile,L4profile):
    print 'li==',li
```

result

```
BEFORE LOOP :

globals()== {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', 'dic': {1: ['a', 'h', 'uu'], 3: ['zer', 'rty'], 4: ['hj', '125', 'qsd']}, '__doc__': None}

keys of globals() not written __xxx__ : dic

-----------------------------------------------------------------
DURING LOOP :

x== 1
keys of globals() not written __xxx__ : L1profile , x , dic
x== 3
keys of globals() not written __xxx__ : L1profile , L3profile , x , dic
x== 4
keys of globals() not written __xxx__ : L1profile , L3profile , x , dic , L4profile

-----------------------------------------------------------------
AFTER LOOP :

keys of globals() not written __xxx__ : L1profile , L3profile , x , dic , L4profile

li== ['a', 'h', 'uu']
li== ['zer', 'rty']
li== ['hj', '125', 'qsd']
```

As the name of objects must not begin with a digit character, 'L' is put systematically as first letter of the created names.